# The method setTabListener(ActionBar.TabListener) in the type ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I setTabListener for a fragment?

I am getting this error:

> The method setTabListener(ActionBar.TabListener) in the type
>   ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity)

```
final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = act.getActionBar();
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(getActivity()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your fragment implement the `ActionBar.TabListener` interface.

Note, though, that action bar tabs were deprecated with Android 5.0, and so you may wish to consider some other tab solution, anyway (e.g., `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator).